# Good easy to learn Ruby on Rails developement platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hoping you guys can help me here, I'm at the end of my tether. I've been on a course to get into the web developement side of things. Only thing is the course is awful. It's completely disorganised.

Long story short I've got a couple of days to hand in a project that involves doing a simple ecom website that can list products, add new ones and have a basic shopping cart. Has to be done through Ruby on Rails and connect to a database. They've had us using Netbeans but so far they can't make it work properly in the college labs and it doesn't work on my laptop either. Does anyone know of a Ruby developeent platform that is easy to instal and use? I've heard good tinhgs about RubyMine but I'm so close to the wire I could really do withsome advice if anyone can help.

---

Comment: I'm assuming you're on a Windows machine?

EDIT: What is it that you're looking for? Do you have Rails set up and running on your system already? Are you just looking for an editor? Are you asking how to actually go about building the application?

Comment: Engine Yard did [a great blog post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/ruby-on-windows-the-last-frontier/) on rails development for windows, that would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: vim for rails is awesome and like... doesn't have a learning curve at all.  Wait maybe it does.

Answer (score 1):

Well I usually code on Ubuntu, and so I just use gedit with the gMate package, so it works and acts like TextMate (Mac). I used to work on a Windows machine too and would just use Notepad++ because all I needed was a basic text editor, but with some more goodness than just plain Notepad.

You can checkout this other question about learning Ruby on Rails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906839/best-way-to-learn-ruby-on-rails-from-scratch/6906885#6906885

Michael Hartl's book (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) is definitely a great way to learn Rails. In it, you basically re-create Twitter. It's really easy to follow, I thought, and you learn a lot. You don't necessarily need to read it straight through though, and can pick and chose what information is relevant to you. But it does go through things like: CRUD (create, retrieve, update, delete) of objects (like creating a new user, showing a user, updating one, deleting one), and how to interact with a database and even how to deploy it on to ye ol' world wide web.

Comment: Hi guys in answer to the comments nothing is really working.  I haven't even got anything started, I am literally building this from scratch.  Yeah, I know.  Believe I didn''t want to be in this position, but my enitre class is in the same boat.  Any help would be grealtly appreciated.